# Unknown Error in xml copy editor (possibly beginners mistake)

Tags: xml

So for a task i need to make xml but when i click on the green check in xml copy editor, I get an error. When clicking on the blue check everything is correct. I'm new so it's possibly a beginners mistake.

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is an entire guide here: https://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/doctype_declaration.shtml

Comment: @NesanMano, it seems that (1) the blue button is checking if your XML is **well-formed**, (2) the green button checks if your XML is **valid**. (3) What XML  editor are you using? Please specify its name in your original post.

Comment: I'm using xml copy editor